# Assign string to another column when enum is selected

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a user permissions function for my web application,

Lets say I have a table which has 2 columns (for example, not practical):

`rank` of `ENUM` type with the values `'guest','user','admin'`

AND another column `permissions`

Is it possible to create this table somehow, using pure `SQL`. Such that, when I update the `rank` column, it will assign the `permissions` column with predefined values. However, I also want to have the possibility of changing the permissions without affecting the `rank` column.

Comment: does a stored procedure count as "pure SQL" ?

Comment: After reading into stored procedures (due to my unfamiliarity with SQL). I wouldn't say it would count, more specifically, I need something that would perform this operation at the stage of `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: great, go write one

Comment: Well, I am asking how this would be done ... After selecting one of the `rank` enumerators. How would I get the table to automatically update/assign a value to the `permissions` column?

Answer (score 0):

We could implement a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

When the specification says "update the rank column", we are meaning when a row (or rows) in the table is affected by an UPDATE statement. We are not meaning altering the table to change the definition of the rank column.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `trg_mytable_bu`
BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

   IF NEW.rank <=> OLD.rank THEN
      -- no change to rank col value
      BEGIN END
   ELSE
      IF NEW.permission IS NULL THEN
         -- defaults apply only if permission value is NULL
         IF NEW.rank = 'guest' THEN 
            SET NEW.permissions = 'fee';
         ELSEIF NEW.rank = 'user' THEN
            SET NEW.permissions = 'fi'; 
         ELSEIF NEW.rank = 'user' THEN
            SET NEW.permissions = 'fo';
         ELSE
            -- unexpected value of rank
            SET NEW.permissions = 'fum';
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

If we want similar "default" assignment behavior for INSERT, we need to define a separate `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, which can be similar, but won't have a reference to OLD.rank.

---

To answer the question that was asked: yes it's possible.

To answer a different question (that wasn't asked)... "Should our design of the database implement a trigger like this?"  To answer that, I think we should rethink the problem, and consider some alternative designs. We'd likely be better served in the long run with a design that doesn't use an ENUM column, and with a design that doesn't require assignment of default values to another column based on the value assigned to ENUM.

Answer (score 0):

You could write AFTER INSERT|UPDATE TRIGGERs for the table; but your design already sounds flawed.

- Your permissions field sounds like you plan for it to hold a list; a field in a row should only hold one value.
- Your use of ENUM also sounds fairly cumbersome, it should only really be used for collections of things that never or almost never change. (Such as gender pre-2000's). You would have to alter/rebuild the table whenever a new rank appeared.

Instead:

- Permissions table: holds permissions.
- Rank table: holds ranks
- Rank permissions: associates ranks and permissions
- Users: holds users
- User ranks: associates ranks and users.

Get user permissions by: joining user to user_ranks to rank_permissions to permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html). However this sounds like the wrong way to solve the problem.

That you use the plural "permissions" to describe the attribute implies it is not atomic, and therefore should not be stored as a single attribute. Further, if you can programmatically derive the permissions from the `rank` then it should be represented as data. Consider:

```
create table permissions (
 Rank enumeration ('guest', 'user', 'admin') 
   not null default 'guest',
 Permission varchar(25)
 Primary key (rank, permission)
);
...
Select u.name, u.rank, u.password,
  u.email, group_concat(P.permission) AS permissions
FROM user u
JOIN permissions p
ON u.rank=p.rank
WHERE u.username='bob'
GROUP BY u.name, u.rank, u.password,
  u.email
```

You can also use this to *resolve* permissions on an object:

```
Select u.name, u.rank, u.password,
  u.email, group_concat(P.permission) AS permissions
FROM user u
JOIN permissions p
ON u.rank=p.rank
JOIN object_permissions op
ON p.permission=op.permission
JOIN object o
ON op.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE u.username='bob'
AND o.name='user admin' 
GROUP BY u.name, u.rank, u.password,
  u.email
```